# IE is activex control installed?

Tags: activex, controls, installation

simple question:How I control my activex is installed on the client?

Answer (score 2):

var p;
        try {
            p = new ActiveXObject('your activex control name');
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("not installed");

        }

its really simple isnt it? good programming :)

Answer (score 0):

The main way is to try creating an instance of it. If the creation fails, then the activex control is NOT installed or some other error happened.